# Deriving functors on subcategories and profinite group cohomology

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors, profinite-groups, galois-cohomology

I am reading through Weibel's chapter on Galois Cohomology and there he defines profinite group cohomology as the right derived functors of the $G$-invariants functor, but restricting to $C_G$, a subcategory of $G$-modules consisting of all discrete modules (i.e. modules with the discrete topology and continuous $G$-action). So essentially we are deriving the composition of the inclusion of $C_G$ into $G$-mod and the invariants functor $G$-mod to $Ab$.

Is there a nice way to describe what happens to derived functors when we precompose with an inclusion like this? In more precise terms, if we have an abelian category with enough injectives $\mathscr{A}$, a left exact functor $F: \mathscr{A}\rightarrow \mathscr{C}$ and a subcategory $\mathscr{B}$ of $\mathscr{A}$ which is also abelian and has enough injectives, what can we say about the right derived functors of the restriction $F:\mathscr{B}\rightarrow \mathscr{C}$?  I have seen that the Grothendieck spectral sequence gives information about the derived functors of a composition of functors, but I do not understand spectral sequences well enough to tell whether it can be applied here.

**Note**: Weibel proves there are enough injectives in $C_G$ by showing the inclusion functor $C_G\rightarrow G-mod$ has a right adjoint, namely the discretization functor, which takes a $G$-module $A$ and outputs the union of all $A^U$, where $U$ ranges over all onen subgroups of the profinite group $G$. (see here: [http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210BPage/handouts/profcohom.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/210BPage/handouts/profcohom.pdf)). Since the discretisation functor is right adjoint to the exact inclusion functor, it preserves injectives.

Comment: $G$-modules (with a topology) are not abelian, there are bijective morphisms between $G$-modules that are not isomorphisms (but they are mono and epi).

Comment: @LukasHeger The categories in question are the category of G-modules (without topology) and the category of discrete G-modules - I think both of these should be abelian? The first one is just $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-mod, which is abelian, and the second one is abelian as well (Weibel exercise 6.11.7)

Comment: you're right, I was confused which categories exactly you consider. I'm not sure whether it is necesserily true that an injective object in $C_G$ is also injective in $G$-mod. That would be important to apply the Grothendieck spectral sequence.

Comment: This doesn’t seem right - if injectives in $C_G$ are injective in $G-mod$, wouldnt injective resolutions in $C_G$ also be injective resolutions in $G-mod$, implying that ordinary and profinite group cohomology coincide?

Comment: There are some important features of the setting that also need to be taken into account: the inclusion of $C_G$ into $G$-mod is exact and has a right adjoint (submodule whose elements have an open stabilizer). In particular, said adjoint maps injective to injectives.

Comment: Yes, that’s how Weibel proves there are enough injectives in $C_G$ - I’ll add a note in the question about this.

Comment: So if anything, the “general” global invariant functor is the composition of the “discretization” functor $D$ (left exact, maps injectives to injectives) and the “global invariants for discrete modules” functor, and you can apply a Grothendieck spectral sequence, [disclaimer: while I think so, I’m not sure what comes next is correct. I don’t understand spectral sequences very well either. I hope someone can check this.] endowing $H^n(G,M)$ (for $M$ a $G$-module) with a filtration whose graded pieces are subquotients of $H^p_{disc}(G,(R^qD)(M))$ (which is the second page) for $p+q=n$.

Comment: A few thoughts: (1) The inclusion $C_G \to G-mod$ is both left and right exact, so I do not expect it to be helpful. (2) I assume your strategy is to try to reduce continuous cohomology to abstract cohomology for computation. But abstract cohomology of a profinite group is generally too large. When working with profinite groups you are usually only interested in continuous modules. (3) It is not too hard to work in $C_G$ directly. If you want to simplify things for a specific module you can work with continuous cocycles or pass to a finite quotient of $G$.